# Relations in NoSql using mongoDB and Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Ok, im comming from an SQL background and I am just getting my hands dirty using MongoDB and Mongoose.

I have two simple models:

CAR:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let carsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  brand: String,
  specfifications: [String],
  image: String

});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Car', carSchema);
```

Driver

```
 let mongoose = require('mongoose');
    let Schema    = mongoose.Schema;
    let driverSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

      name: String,
      cars: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Car' }]

    });
    module.exports = mongoose.model('Driver', driverSchema);
```

From what I can understand, this seems to be a proper way of handling a one-to-many-relationship where one car can be used by many drivers.

Now I need to add a class called `Races` which will be used for saving the results for spacific driver in a specific car.

Thinking in SQL I would do something like this:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let raceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  totaltime: String,
  laptime: String,
  driver: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Driver' },
  car: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Car' }

});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Race', raceSchema);
```

Would you consider this to be to correct approach in NoSql or am I forcing my SQL-way of thinking into NoSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is it depends

MongoDB or NoSQL theory says if all related data are in one document, then your query will run faster as they will be stored together. So, in most cases we would prefer one single model for both Car and Driver

If you do not query car and drivers together in most of your queries (chances for which would be rare), then what you did is also correct.

Also, MongoDB has a limitation on size of document i.e. 16 MB if you think the cost of storing them together can go beyond 16MB then what you did is correct. However, there is an alternate solution i.e. GridFS which stores the documents into chunks and overcomes this limitation

Comment: Ok thank you!
So a combined model for both the car and the driver you say. Would you include the ´race´ in that model as well?

Comment: If you can then yes, again the models should be designed how you query i.e. if you often query things together and they fit in 16MB (which is good enough for most cases)